# Mais uma ausência de tradução

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tradução, internacionalização

Mais uma ausência de tradução na página de fechamento de pergunta:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não vou marcar como duplicata, mas a parte do "pertence a outro site" já estava registrada aqui: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/774/frases-em-ingl%C3%AAs-ao-sinalizar-postagem